# A Joint density problem with constraints.

Tags: integration

Hoping someone with more smarts than myself can let me know if I am doing this right.

The solution I arrive at is $-\infty$ and I am unsure if that makes any sense at all. Grateful for any help.

Question

A joint density function is given by

$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
e^{-x-y}                           & \text {for $x\ge0, y\ge0$} \\
\\
0   & \text{otherwise} \\
\end{cases} $

Find $ P(x+y\le2)$

The integral I came up with is

$ \int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{2-y} e^{-x-y} \,dx dy$

which evaluates as

$ \int_{0}^{2-y} e^{-x-y} \,dx  =e^{-y}-\frac{1}{e^2}$

and

$ \int_{0}^{\infty}(e^{-y}-\frac{1}{e^2})\,dy  =-\infty-(-1)$

So is  $-\infty$  a valid answer or have i messed up somewhere?

Comment: Note that $x+y\ge 2$ with $x,y\ge 0$ implies $0\le x\le 2$ and $0\le y \le 2-x.$ So you have to evaluate $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2-y} e^{-x-y} \,dx dy$

Comment: "Is $-\infty$ a valid answer?" You are trying to calculate the *probability of an event*. Hence, the answer must be a number between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: oh. that makes much more sense. will give it a go. thanks so much

Comment: So my outside integral is 

$ \int_{0}^{2}(e^{-y}-\frac{1}{e^2})\,dy  =1-\frac{3}{e^2}=0.59$